# Convert formatted string to latitude or longitude

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have used OpenLayers to generate a formatted latitude; like this:

```
OpenLayers.Util.getFormattedLonLat(bounds.top, 'lat');
```

which produces the string `57°42'32"N`. The value of `bounds.top` is 57.70889832055789 in decimal degrees.

This is fine. But how can I do the reverse using OpenLayers? If a user enters a String like `57°42'32"N` how can I use OpenLayers to convert it into decimal degrees as used by e.g. `OpenLayers.LonLat` or `OpenLayers.Bounds`?

Comment: What is the format required for [input](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/LonLat-js.html), e.g. decimal degrees or some from of character separated values?

Comment: Decimal degrees is used for input to LonLat.

Answer (score 2):

It should be enough to parse the string and calculate the rational number from the Degrees, minutes and seconds like:

```
var input = "50° 20' 12''";
var coord = input.match(/[0-9]+/g);
var lat = parseFloat(coord[0]) + coord[1]/60.0 + coord[2]/3600.0 ;
if(/S|W/i.test(input)) lat *= -1;
```

Of course you should check for correctness of the input and init the array with at 3 fields 0.

Comment: Yes; this will work. But I was searching for a way to use OpenLayers for the purpose. Perhaps your code should be contributed to them :-)

Comment: Ok, not sure, there does not already exist such a method, but this would be far more robust, as there is a number of possible formats in which a LatLong could be. See [http://www.geomidpoint.com/latlon.html](http://www.geomidpoint.com/latlon.html)

Comment: Instead of *match*, the above could use `input.split(/\D+/g)`, the difference is that *split* will always return an array, whereas *match* might return null, but deals with leading and trailing non–digits better. Either way, the result should be tested before being used.